# How to check selected time is within the given time range in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exchangewebservices

I need to determine if the selected times (start time, end time) by the user is in the array of appointment times.

I get the appointment times from exchange web service and the output is :

```
[{Status: "Busy", StartTime: "2016-10-05T11:00:00+10:00", EndTime: "2016-10-05T11:30:00+10:00"},{Status: "Busy", StartTime: "2016-10-05T13:00:00+10:00", EndTime: "2016-10-05T15:30:00+10:00"}]
```

The times that user has selected are :

```
var start_time = Date.parse("2016-10-05T14:30");
var end_time = Date.parse("2016-10-05T15:00");
```

So far I have tried the following but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it:

```
var data = [{Status: "Busy", StartTime: "2016-10-05T11:00:00+10:00", EndTime: "2016-10-05T11:30:00+10:00"},{Status: "Busy", StartTime: "2016-10-05T13:00:00+10:00", EndTime: "2016-10-05T15:30:00+10:00"}];

for (var key in data)
{
  var obj = data[key];
  if (obj['Status'] == 'Busy')
  {
    check_open_time_val = Date.parse(obj['StartTime']);
    check_close_time_val = Date.parse(obj['EndTime']);

     if (check_open_time_val > open_time)
     {
        console.log('Is Busy');
        // break;
        return true;
      }
   }else {
      console.log(obj['Status'] + 'XXXXX');
   }
  }
```

How do I check if the start_time and the endtime are not in any of the appointment times.
Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to detect if there's any overlap with the user time range and the busy time ranges?

Comment: Thanks @Phil, that is exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [this logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) with [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
let data = [{Status: "Busy", StartTime: "2016-10-05T11:00:00+10:00", EndTime: "2016-10-05T11:30:00+10:00"},{Status: "Busy", StartTime: "2016-10-05T13:00:00+10:00", EndTime: "2016-10-05T15:30:00+10:00"}],
    start_time = Date.parse("2016-10-05T14:30:00+10:00"),
    end_time = Date.parse("2016-10-05T15:00:00+10:00");

let isClash = data.some(obj => {
    let s = Date.parse(obj.StartTime), e = Date.parse(obj.EndTime);

    return obj.Status === 'Busy' && start_time <= e && end_time >= s;
});

console.log('is clash?', isClash);
```

Note that I aligned the UTC offsets of your `start_time` and `end_time` so you could see that it works :)